# CSS not applying to newly added elements through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm adding a new `<div>` to the page on button click. The problem is that the styling isn't applying to the new div, well to parts of it, mainly the inner divs which is where i need it. I have looked at some questions and tried using escape charaters but nothing seems to work.

The styling works if the div is there when the page loads.

The javascript to add the div:

```
AddNewSection: function () {
    var me = IndexController;        
    $("#addNew").before('<div id="New' + me.options.count + '" class="block center">\
                            <div style="width:100%;flex:1;display:inline-flex" >\
                                <div class="group">\
                                    <input id="Question' + me.options.count + '" type="text" class="inputHighlight">\
                                    <span class="bar"></span>\
                                    <label class="labelHighlight">Question</label>\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="group">\
                                    <label>Type</label>\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="group">\
                                    <input id="Drop'+ me.options.count + '" value="1" />\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                            <div id="TypeDiv'+ me.options.count + '">\
                            </div>\
                        </div>');
    me.CreateDropDown(me.options.count);
    me.options.count++;
},
```

The div that is hardcoded on the page:

```
<div id="New1" class="block center">
<div style="width:100%;flex:1;display:inline-flex">
    <div class="group">
        <input id="Question1" type="text" class="inputHighlight" required>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label class="labelHighlight">Question</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <label>Type</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input id="Drop1" value="1" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="TypeDiv1">
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
p {
    margin: 10px;
}

body {
    background: white;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#Page {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin: 60px auto;
    font: normal 12px/21px sans-serif;
    color: #444;
}

    #Page.wide {
        width: 70%;
    }

    #Page.narrow {
        width: 30%;
    }

    #Page:before, #Page:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        display: none;
    }

    #Page.top-shadow:before {
        display: block;
        top: 0px;
        clip: rect(-40px auto 0 auto);
    }

    #Page.bottom-shadow:after {
        display: block;
        bottom: 0px;
        clip: rect(20px auto 40px auto);
    }

.AddNew {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100px;
    border: thin solid #ddd;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.center {
    margin: 15px auto 15px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.block {
    width: 90%;
    height: 150px;
    border: thin solid #ddd;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

    .block.center {
        margin: 15px auto 15px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

.group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.inputHighlight {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
}

    .inputHighlight:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

/* LABEL ======================================= */
.labelHighlight {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

/* active state */
.inputHighlight:focus ~ .labelHighlight, .inputHighlight:valid ~ .labelHighlight {
    top: -10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5264AE;
}

/* BOTTOM BARS ================================= */
.bar {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
}

    .bar:before, .bar:after {
        content: '';
        height: 2px;
        width: 0;
        bottom: 1px;
        position: absolute;
        background: #5264AE;
        transition: 0.2s ease all;
        -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
    }

    .bar:before {
        left: 50%;
    }

    .bar:after {
        right: 50%;
    }

/* active state */
.inputHighlight:focus ~ .bar:before, .inputHighlight:focus ~ .bar:after {
    width: 50%;
}
```

The output:

[image: Display]

Let me know if you need anything else.

Thank you in davance.

Comment: Can you share the `css` as well that you are using for this.

Comment: @UtsavPatel Sure, will update now

Comment: @UtsavPatel Added.

Comment: I think, add setTimeout function for adding custom styles into appened div.

Comment: The structure you're adding is **different** to the structure that's hardcoded. (And the hardcoded structure in the question isn't closed.) So apparently the CSS relies on the structure. If you use the Inspect feature of your browser you'll be able to see the differences. If you need the structures to be identical, I'd suggest using a template and cloning it, etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, The input field needed the required requirement.